# IE Tooltip displays underneath link text

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, hyperlink, tooltip

Only on IE the tooltip shows underneath the text of the link therefore the text in the tooltip can't be read. I know I could move the tooltip over to the right but that doesn't look good.
How can I make the tooltip background solid or on top of the links. I already tried z-index.

```
<ul style=" list-style: circle;  margin: 0px 2px 0px 12px;">
    <li style="z-index:10">
        <a class="tooltip" href="abc.com"> <span class="classic" ><%= content %></span></a>
    </li>
</ul>
.classic  
{
    padding: 0.8em 1em; 
    display:none; 
    text-decoration: none;
     list-style: circle;
     background:#FFC62E;
}

.tooltip {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #000000;
  color: #000000; 
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative; 
}
.tooltip span 
{
    display:inline;
  margin-left: -999em;
  position: absolute;
  text-decoration: none; 
  color:#000000;
}
.tooltip:hover span {
  font-family: Calibri, Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  left: 1em;
  top: 2em;
  z-index: 1; 
  margin-left: 170;
  width: 250px;
  display:inline-block;
  background-color: #FFC62E; 
  background:rgb(255,198,46); 
  position:absolute;
  text-decoration: none; 
  color:#000000;
  border-radius: 5px 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

Comment: `background: black;` you have tried? Can you set up a jsfiddle maybe?

Comment: if you want a good cross-browser tooltip experience I would recommend using a jQuery plugin like this one: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/ you can and will pull out all of your hair trying to get them to work with IEs (and other browsers) nuiances

Comment: background-color:black just changes the background to black. tooltip still underneath the link.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/br6AP/

Comment: Good try, but if you add more long strings <li> you still see the <a> text through the tooltip. Now the tooltip is on top of the text though.